# Best practice to insert a lot of objects in Realm

Tags: objective-c, realm

I was wondering if someone knows whats the best practice to inserting/updating a large amount of objects in Realm?

For example, lets say I have `ParentObject`, which has a `RLMArray` to `ChildObject`. Imagine `ParentObject` had 10,000 `ChildObject` records that needed to be persisted in the database. What would be the best way to handle saves like this without killing the I/O and user experience? I am a little slightly hesitant to store all the objects (all 10,001) objects in memory as the objects could be very large and use up a lot of memory, causing instability in the app.

Answer (score 1):

## Benchmark

Here you can find a benchmark of how Realm is performing with different numbers of objects: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/796

## Not killing User-Experience

You can always do things on other threads than the main thread.

## Loading objects in memory

You need to be efficient with memory, but that doesn't concern Realm. Let's say you are reading data from disk. You should build objects in batches and call Realm insert multiple times.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I saw this post a while back, but I was hoping more so if someone would be able to demonstrate how to process objects in batches.

Comment: as mention in above git url, you can use this method "[realm transactionWithBlock:^{ //your code to store data }];" and write your code in block.